# get location(x,y) of matched features in two images using emgu

Tags: algorithm, emgucv, surf

i have two images taken by two cameras, i want to use surf algorithm or any algorithm in Emgu to get just matched features locations in two images to calculates (estimate) real distance from cameras and this features (objects), i found example to use surf algorithm in Emgu examples, but its draw lines between matched features i want to get x and y for any begin and end of each line.
[features matched by surf algorithm sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poT1u.jpg)

i try to add some code in surf algorithm example but not work as expected in Draw method

```
long num_matches = matches.Size;
float lower = matches[0][0].Distance;
List<PointF> matched_points1= new List<PointF>();
List<PointF> matched_points2=new List<PointF>();

for (int i = 0; i < num_matches; i++)
{
    if (matches[i][0].Distance < 0.095)
    { 
        int idx1 = matches[i][0].TrainIdx;
        int idx2 = matches[i][0].QueryIdx;
        matched_points1.Add(observedKeyPoints[idx1].Point);
        matched_points2.Add(observedKeyPoints[idx2].Point);
        CvInvoke.Circle(result, new Point((int)observedKeyPoints[idx2].Point.X , (int)observedKeyPoints[idx2].Point.Y), 1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));
        CvInvoke.Circle(result, new Point((int)modelKeyPoints[idx1].Point.X + modelImage.Width, (int)modelKeyPoints[idx1].Point.Y), 1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));
    }

    if (lower > matches[i][0].Distance)
        lower = matches[i][0].Distance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Point[] FindPoints(Mat modelImage, Mat observedImage, out long matchTime)
  {
      Mat homography;
      VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
      VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
      using (VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch())
      {
          Mat mask;
  FindMatch(modelImage, observedImage, out matchTime, out modelKeyPoints, out      observedKeyPoints, matches,out mask, out homography);

          //Draw the matched keypoints
          Mat result = new Mat();
          Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, observedImage, observedKeyPoints,
             matches, result, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), mask);

          Point[] points = null;
          if (homography != null)
          {
              //draw a rectangle along the projected model
              Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, modelImage.Size);
              PointF[] pts = new PointF[]
            {
               new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Bottom),
               new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Bottom),
               new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Top),
               new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Top)
            };
              pts = CvInvoke.PerspectiveTransform(pts, homography);

              points = Array.ConvertAll<PointF, Point>(pts, Point.Round);

          }

          return points;
      }
  }
```

//add the code in the Draw function

```
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Size; i++) { var a = matches[i].ToArray(); if (mask.GetData(i)[0] == 0) continue; foreach (var e in a) { Point p = new `Point(e.TrainIdx, e.QueryIdx); Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Point: {0}", p)); } Console.WriteLine("-----------------------"); }`
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I've managed to get some points out of the matches objects like this:              for (int i = 0; i < matches.Size; i++)
{
    var a = matches[i].ToArray();
    if (mask.GetData(i)[0] == 0)
        continue;
    foreach (var e in a)
    {
        Point p = new Point(e.TrainIdx, e.QueryIdx);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Point: {0}", p));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
}

Comment: Please also don't post code in comments - if you have an update to your answer, [edit] it instead.